# Max deep sleep arduino esp8266

Tags: arduino

He estado tratando de enviar mi **Arduino D1Mini** a un sueño profundo y en mi código intento despertarlo cada 8 horas. Leyendo la documentación sobre `DeepSleep` me di cuenta de que hay un máximo de 8 horas. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal en el *sketch*, porque se despierta a los 30 minutos cada vez. Es el tiempo máximo que puedes dormir. ¿Podría alguien ayudarme con esto? no puedo entender ese es mi código.

(La función consiste en un simple **Arduino D1Mini**, que se conecta a una `wifi` y envía datos desde un sensor analógico a un servidor `Thingspeak`. Después de eso, me gustaría que pudiera dormir más de una hora sin despertarse).

```
  system_deep_sleep_set_option(1);
  system_deep_sleep_instant(1990000 * 1000);
```

Comment: Voy a probar tu código tan pronto averigüe cual librería y toolchain estas usando.

Comment: La placa que estás usando no es "Arduino Mini", es un Wemos D1. Los Arduino no tiene WiFi.

Comment: Buen día, según la documentación debes conectar el pin `RST` al pin `GPIO 16` que debe estar marcado como `D0`. Eso no lo mencionas en tu pregunta, ¿Está cableado de esa forma? Otra cosa, las unidades del deepSleep son en micro segundos, has puesto 33 minutos, si deseas 8 horas debes poner `2.88e10`

Comment: Buenas, gracias a todos. Esta cableado con el RST y el GPIO 16, lo cual resetea bien, el problema es que se hace a los 33 minutos, y no dura mas tiempo. La placa si, es un D1 Mini, quizás me exprese mal. Uso la libreria de Wifi <ESP8266WiFi.h>, y puedo conectarme, así que no creo que ese sea el problema. SI es necesario, especificaré todo lo que sea posible

Comment: Lo cierto, HeytalePazguato, es que si subo de 2190000 en  system_deep_sleep_instant(2190000 * 1000), no se va a dormir, si no que vuelve a ejecutar la función directamente. Por eso no consigo entender si es un error de la funcion, si no permite más, o puedo hacer algo para remediarlo. Anteriormente usé otra función para dormir que era ESP.deepSleep("tiempo a dormir"), pero haciendo eso, no duerme de una manera tan profunda como el comando de system_deep_sleep_instant. Necesito que se duerma de la manera mas profunda posible, y con ESP.deepSleep gasta 10 mA y en system.... solo 2 microamperios

Comment: @JulianPerez, Mira, encontré un [tutorial paso a paso](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-deep-sleep-with-arduino-ide/), espero que te sirva

Comment: @HeytalePazguato ¡Muchas gracias! Ha sido de utilidad. Un fuerte abrazo, ten un buen dia

Comment: Perfecto, te invito a que tu mismo escribas la respuesta a tu pregunta y la aceptes, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se ha solucionado haciendo este comando:

```
ESP.deepSleep(18e+9, WAKE_RF_DEFAULT);  //Unidad de tiempo = micro segundos
```

Antes lo dormía de otra manera, pensando que este comando tenía un mínimo de `mA` para dormir, y me he dado cuenta de que con este comando consume `0,2 microamperios` durmiendo.